# How can I copy all of the rows that correspond to a specific account number, into a new sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a worksheet with headers of "account number", "name", "part", etc.

I want to take each account from this data, and create a new sheet with only the rows for that specific account. I don't care if it is cutting it right from the original sheet, or if it is copying it into the new sheet. I want to repeat this process for each account, until I have essentially parsed the entire sheet.

A few things:

1. My goal is to run a report specific for each account, which is why I need them on their own individual sheets. So advanced filter won't work for this.
2. I have been trying to find a way to use an Index Match function, but am not coming up with the correct solution.

Comment: Have you considered using a [pivot table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) to create your reports?

Comment: index match will do what you want. Please add some details of what you have tried, and what is not working. Also, some examples for the two sheets should look like if everything was working.

Comment: Can I just ask, why is Advanced Filter not working for you? It's designed to do exactly what you describe. If you start from your target sheet, create your criteria, then run Advanced Filter, you'll find an option on there for "Copy to another location". That would allow you to do more or less exactly what you describe, though it won't do it automatically for each sheet...

Comment: Lot of good comments, I was not as diligent as I should have been with the advanced filter, because yes, that does seem to be the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid this being left "Unanswered", I'll shift my comment into an answer.

The Advanced Filter is the tool to use for this job. To use it, we need a couple of steps.

First, let's assume your data looks something like this:

[image: Data]

We want to pull everything with account number 123-456 to a new sheet. Go to a new sheet, and add a header that matches the column you're filtering for on the main sheet. Below that, add the value you want to filter for.

[image: Criteria]

You can add multiple headers and multiple rows if you want to filter by multiple criteria or pull multiple matches in.

When you're happy with your criteria, go to the Data tab and click Advanced next to the Filter button. Be sure to have the DESTINATION tab active when you do this:

[image: Filter button]

This opens the Advanced Filter interface, which we'll use to finish the process. For our purposes:

- **Action** should be set to *Copy to another location*
- **List Range** is the range containing the original data. Make sure you include the header row, since that's what it will use to match the criteria.
- **Criteria Range** is the range of cells containing the criteria we created on the new sheet. Again, be sure to include the header row.
- **Copy To** should be a range on the current sheet representing the top-left of the area you want the data returned to.

[image]

When you click OK, you should find all the rows from your List Range where your criteria match will be copied to the new location. It will be a single contiguous range, without any gaps where old data was or similar. You can now manipulate it as you wish.

The advantage of this method is that it does allow very precise and complex criteria to be used to create a subset of your data. The biggest disadvantage is that it can be kind of cumbersome, especially if you need to do it many times.